# Huge PersistentMapping persisted on every content object save in Plone

Tags: plone, zope, zodb

every time I save an object, I get this warning in the instance log:

```
[..]deployment/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/ZODB/Connection.py:660: UserWarning: The <class 'persistent.mapping.PersistentMapping'>
object you're saving is large. (29343532 bytes.)
```

and indeed, saving takes long. Putting a pdb into the place where this is printed triggers during the transaction commit and shows me indeed that a PersistentMapping is written of type:

```
{1: path_to_a_content_object,
 2: path_to_other_content_object,
 ...
 129000: path_to_yetanother_content_object }
```

It seems I have one entry for every content object in my site. As this happens during commit, I cannot see where that mapping is stored.

Does anybody have a pointer what that could be?

Thanks a lot!
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://plone.org/documentation/kb/debug-zodb-bloat

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped! The PersistentMapping is kept by CMFNotifications. We have successfully replaced that with an IOBTree and prepare a fix.

Comment: This is happening to me but I don't believe I am using CMFNotifications. Any advice?